# Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate does not commit when repository.save

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, commit

I have a Spring Boot Application + JPA with MySQL. In my controller, when I post an entity I am able to call to repository.save, and I return the "created/updated" object.

But, when I look at the database, I see that the object is not updated.

Here is my application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete: true
      org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag: true
      org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision: true
  datasource:
    initialize: false
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:${DB_PORT:3306}/${DB_NAME:databaseName}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: ${DB_USERNAME:root}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:root}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    hikari:
      minimumIdle: 20
      maximumPoolSize: 30
      idleTimeout: 5000
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
```

Do you know what else do I have to do?

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public MyEntity saveMyEntity(@Valid @RequestBody final MyEntity myEntity) {
    Assert.notNull(myEntity, "The entry cannot be null");
    return myEntityService.save(myEntity);
}
```

And MyEntityService:

```
@Override
@UserCanCud
public Entity save(final Entity entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity);
    final Entity savedEntity = repository.save(entity);
    return savedEntity;
}
```

Comment: add the controller method which calls the save

Comment: Post edited. I hope it is clear

Comment: Where's your transaction boundary?

Comment: Hi Stefan, I did not understand your question. Do you mean if I have methods annotated with @Transactional ?

Comment: In order to persist / update you  need to be within a transaction.. a method  should be marked with @Transactional in your case as you are using annotations

Comment: maybe that is the reason I cannot save. Because I do not have a @Transactional annotation.

Comment: I added Transactional annotation to my service, and EnableTransactionManagement and still does not save. Am I doing something wring?

Comment: have you set autocommit to false somewhere?

Comment: No, I'm using hikaricp and, I even set autoCommit: true

Comment: What's the repository look like?

Comment: The repository looks like this: 

    @Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, BigInteger>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> { }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the solution... the entity I was trying to update had the @Immutable annotation on it...

Answer (score 16):

In my (limited) experience these types of problems are a tad more difficult to debug because of the magic happening behind the scenes with Spring, but I'll try to give some advice that has helped me troubleshoot similar problems - hopefully this gives you the nudge you need.

The `@Transactional` notation establishes a *transactional* scope that dictates when a transaction starts and ends, also called its boundary. If you operate outside of this boundary you'll either receive errors or things just won't work as expected.

First off, I found this bit of documentation the most helpful on Spring transactions: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html specifically [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation)

Secondly, you may wish to enable trace level logs and potentially the SQL statements to help debug this. In order to do so I added the following to my `application.properties` - You'll be able to add the same into your `application.yml` with some minor adjustments

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate=TRACE
```

There will be ALOT of output here, but you'll get a good idea of whats happening behind the scenes.

Third, and the most important part for me in learning how to use `@Transactional` is that every call to the DAO creates a new session -or- reuses the existing session if within the same transactional scope. Refer to the documentation above for examples of this.

Now, I suspect that your transaction is still considered open when you're reading back your updated object. Try doing a `flush` in your save method and see if that helps persist your changes back to the database.

Hopefully you'll be able to find the issue without too much hunting using the resources above, if not you should at the very least have some more complete information surrounding why the persistence isn't persisting.

Comment: Hi Robert,

Thanks for your comment, I already tried before your comment to be more verbose to see what is going on under the hood, but still, I could not make it work.

Just another comment, when the entity is created (id is null), then, the transaction is finished... I can see the insert into statements,  but I can't when I try to update an entity.

Comment: What happens if you search for the entity using `repository.find()`, and update the returned entity?

Comment: Hi Robert, I tried what you said, doing this, repository.findOne(myEntity.getId), and then myEntity.setOneField(newValue); repository.save() and still did not save it....

Comment: Ok - is `repository` an instance of `EntityManager` or is it an instance of your `RepositoryImpl` which contains the `EntityManager`? Assuming its your `RepositoryImpl`, is `save()` calling `entityManager.merge(entity)` or is it calling `persist()`?

Comment: well... I am using spring data, so Repository it is just an interface.

Comment: heh, I'm used to providing my own custom implementations - Behind the scenes with the auto wiring Save calls either persist or merge 
 (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites). To be honest, I am not sure how much more help I can be here - I still suspect your transaction boundaries are at least partially to blame here, but I would suggest that you spin up a side project, implement spring data and a basic use case and see if you still have problems or if the problems are only in your current code base. Hope this has helped...

Comment: Hi Robert, The complete code can be found here https://github.com/manuelarte/TeambuiltingPlayers, just in case you are bored and want to take a look :)

Comment: Annotate `saveMyEntity` with `@Transactional` and check whether the entity is visibly update in the database after the method finished.

Comment: Since you already tried verbose output I'm guessing there is no SQL UPDATE after the save? If there isn't, you might really have to go deeper and debug the implementation to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the interception that you do with the annotation @UserCanCud.

I just made a project with the same settings that you propose and it works correctly. Take a look at:

https://github.com/nitzap/spring-data-mysql

If I'm missing something, just let me know.

Comment: Hi German,

mmm, strange, because I tried by removing the annotation, and also the aspect and still does not update it.

Comment: You could try the example I sent you. Able we can determine that the problem is outside your project.

Answer (score 0):

To save your object you need to setup proper jpa configurations and the repository after that it will be save.

for example we have user entity and userRepository as below

`User Enity Class`

```
package com.sanjeev.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

 //getters and setters   
}
```

`User Repository class`

```
package com.sanjeev.repository;    
    import com.sanjeev.domain.User;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    }
```

`User Service class`

```
package com.sanjeev.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.sanjeev.repository.UserRepository;
import com.sanjeev.domain.User;

@Service
public class UserService{

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  public void saveUser(User user){
    userRepository.save(user);
  }


}
```

`If you will follow above steps then your object must me saved`

for more [click here](http://www.jhaji.in/2016/08/jpa-configuration-with-spring-boot.html)

Comment: Hi sanjeevha, I do not think that I am doing it wrong. I am following above steps and still not working.

Comment: actually i did it recently on my machine and it working perfectly, if you follow the given link then it might be possible you will get more idea

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if it helps anyone, **i have separate controllers for ReadRepos and WriteRepos** and was using different databases(one as master, other as slave).
Technically both repos extend CRUD repos directly or indirectly via JPA repository both can access save(Entity e) method.

So, while using the readRepo accidentally to save , it was silently ignoring the call, instead of throwing error.

So bottomline ,is make sure you are using writeRepo to save/update if you have the same situation